# Proving the cardinality of a finite set

Tags: isabelle

How can I prove in Isabelle the simple `lemma cd : "card {m∈ℕ. m <4} = 4"` statement?

`auto` doesn't help me and oddly `sledgehammer` times out (even if I use different values on the right-hand side, like `3` or `5` to make sure that I haven't overlooked some technical Isabelle details which perhaps actually make the cardinaliy evaluate to one of these numbers.)

I have the impression that I have to use some lemmas (or get inspiration) from `Set_Interval.thy` as there sets of these kind are extensively used, but so far I didn't manage to make progress.

Comment: Please post on math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Jameson You misunderstood the question - this is not about maths, but about *formalization" of math (in Isabelle), which is very much in the scope of this site - there are a lot of similar questions here. I added the wording "in Isabelle" to my question, if the tag didn't clarify this.

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to add, that if you rewrite your lemma to `"card {m::nat. m < n} = n"`, Isabelle has no problem proving it.

*Edited, thanks Manuel.

Comment: You probably mean `card {m::nat. m < n} = n`. Good observation; maybe this is what OP had in mind. It's a very different statement though, as one can see from my answer. A good reminder that theorem proving is always an exercise in subtleties.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your statement is that it is not true. Look at the definition of ℕ with `thm Nats_def`: `ℕ = range of_nat`

`of_nat` is the canonical homomorphism from the naturals into a `semiring_1`, i.e. a semiring that has a 1. The definition of ℕ basically says that ℕ consists of all the elements of the ring that are of the form `of_nat n` for a natural number `n`. If you look at the type of `{m∈ℕ. m <4}`, you will see that it is `'a`, or if you do a `declare [[show_sorts]]` before it, `'a :: {ord, semiring_1}`, i.e. a semiring with a 1 and some kind of ordering on it. This ordering does *not* have to be compatible with the ring structure, nor does it have to be linear.

You may think that the set you defined is always the set `{0, 1, 2, 3}`, but because the ordering is not required to be compatible with the ring structure, this is not the case. The ordering could be trivially true, so you'll get *all* natural numbers.

Furthermore, even when the set *is* `{0, 1, 2, 3}`, its cardinality is not necessarily 4. (Think of the ring ℤ/2ℤ – then that set will be equal to `{0, 1}`, so the cardinality is 2)

You will probably want to restrict the type of your expression a bit. I think the right type class here is `linordered_semidom`, i.e. a semiring with a 1, no zero divisors, and a linear ordering that is compatible to the ring structure. Then you can do:

```
lemma cd : "card {m∈ℕ. m < (4 :: 'a :: linordered_semidom)} = 4"
proof -
  have "{m∈ℕ. m < (4 :: 'a)} = {m∈ℕ. m < (of_nat 4 :: 'a)}" by simp
  also have "… = of_nat ` {m. m < 4}"
    unfolding Nats_def by (auto simp del: of_nat_numeral)
  also have "card … = 4" by (auto simp: inj_on_def card_image)
  finally show ?thesis .
qed
```

The proof is a bit ugly considering how intuitively obvious the proposition is; the solution here is not to write down the set you want to describe in this relatively inconvenient way in the first place. It takes a bit of experience to know how to write things in a convenient way.

Comment: Wow, I never would have expected that `m∈ℕ` vs `n::nat` make so a big difference. Thanks a lot for the comprehensive answer.

Comment: As I said, HOL is a typed logic. This is often confusing for mathematicians in the beginning. Similar issues often arise in traditional mathematics as well though: for example, how many elements does the set `[1;10]` have? Ten? Or infinitely many. Depends on whether you see it as a set of naturals or reals. Similarly, is `(0;1)` open? It is as a subset of ℝ, but not as a subset of ℂ.